Error when using emacs in background process: [1] + suspended (tty output) emacs
I get this error when I try to open any file in the background using emacs:
[1] + suspended (tty output) emacs file

Your question is much too short to be clear. What are you doing, exactly? What is in the background? Where are you seeing this message? What do you expect to happen? Please edit your question to include answers to these questions plus any other information that might be relevant.
